# Hover not working and I don't know why

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I am a beginner trying to make my own website. I have had troubles trying to position an image and endow it with a hover property, here's the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Tu est fis de pute</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <style>
    div {
      height: 30px;
      width: 30px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 45%;
      left: 25%;
      -webkit-transition: width 2s, height 2s;
      transition: width 2s, height 2s;
    }
    div:hover {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <img src="logo.png" style="width:13%; position:absolute; top:11%; left:44.2%" />
  <div id="fbicon">
    <img src="icons/facebook.png" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am basically trying to bring a enlargement effect when hovered over the icon, whilst putting the icon where I want. Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Works just fine for me - Take a look here https://jsfiddle.net/19mr3vuk/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scale` to enlarge whole div on hover:

```css
div {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  background: teal;
  top: 45%;
  left: 25%;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
div:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<img src="logo.png" style="width:13%; position:absolute; top:11%; left:44.2%" />
<div id="fbicon">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-50-50-2.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this only change css bottom line:

HTML

```
<img src="logo.png" style="width:13%; position:absolute; top:11%; left:44.2%"/>
<div id="fbicon"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-50-50-2.jpg"/> </div>
```

CSS

```
div{
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 25%;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s, height 2s;
    transition:  width 2s, height 2s;
}
div:hover{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
div img{width:100%; height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code didn't work because you are only changing the `height` and `width` of the `div` but **the `image` inside its parent `div` still have the same height and width**.

Either you change the image size with respect to its parent `div` like

```
div img{
   width:100%; 
   height:100%;
}
```

Or directly apply the hover effect on the image.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="fbicon">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-50-50-2.jpg"/> 
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
 div img {
      height: 30px;
      width: 30px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 20%;
      left: 25%;
      -webkit-transition: width 2s, height 2s;
      transition: width 2s, height 2s;
    }
    div img:hover {
      width: 80px;
      height: 80px;
    }
```