# How make image larger while mouse over using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I need to make image larger/like zoom while mouse hover on that particular image. Here is my code:

```
<div ng-repeat="mul in mulImage">
  <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
    <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Image{{$index+1}}:</span>

        <input type="file" class="filestyle form-control" data-size="lg" name="upload_{{$index}}" id="bannerimage_{{$index}}" ng-model="mul.image" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB" ngf-select="onFileSelect1($index);">


        <span class="input-group-btn" ng-show="mulImage.length>0">
            <img ngf-thumbnail="mul.image" name="pro" border="0" style="width:32px; height:32px; border:#808080 1px solid;" ng-if="mul.image !=null"><img ng-src="upload/{{mul.filename}}" name="pro" border="0" style="width:32px; height:32px; border:#808080 1px solid;" ng-if="mul.filename!=''">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="plus" id="plus" value="+" ng-click="addNewImageRow(mulImage);" ng-show="$last"> <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="minus" id="minus" value="-"  ng-show="mulImage.length>1" ng-click="deleteNewImageRow(mulImage,$index);">

        </span>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Here I am selecting the multiple images by creating new file field using `+` button. My controller side code are given below:

```
$scope.mulImage=[];
   $scope.mulImage.push({'image':null,'filename':''});
   console.log('mulimage',$scope.mulImage);
   $scope.addNewImageRow=function(mulImage){
       console.log('total image',mulImage.length);
       mulImage.push({'image':null,'filename':''});
       console.log('end total image',mulImage.length);

   }
   $scope.deleteNewImageRow=function(mulImage,index){
       mulImage.splice(index,1);
       console.log('file',$scope.mulImage);
   }
   $scope.onFileSelect1 = function(index) {
         $scope.mulImage[index]['filename']='';

   }
```

Here I need after selecting image from drive while user will mouse hover on that image the image will became larger and is user will mouse out again the image will come out its original position. Here is my [plunkr working code](https://plnkr.co/edit/iaiIzFTXjrRWDT2AqBLr?p=preview).

Comment: Refer to this link. Similar to this que.Its all related to CSS
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42219844/hover-not-working-and-i-dont-know-why

Comment: @Akash Ryan soln should work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **CSS** to do the Hover Effect using **transform: scale(1.1)**:

```
.input-group-btn:hover img {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Comment: Its not coming as per expected. The should more large.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code-

```
.image { 
width:250px; 
height:250px;
margin-right:10px;
float:left; 
overflow:hidden; 
cursor:pointer; 
}

.image > img { 
-webkit-transition:all 500ms linear; 
-moz-transition:all 500ms linear; 
-o-transition:all 500ms linear; 
-ms-transition:all 500ms linear; 
transition:all 500ms linear; 
}

.image > img:hover { 
-moz-transform: scale(1.5); 
-webkit-transform: scale(1.5); 
-o-transform: scale(1.5); 
transform: scale(1.5); 
}
```

Refer this link-http://fiddle.jshell.net/Talsja/f6awjwty/